# Refusing Google Analytics cookies for GDPR with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cookies

This is a new problem I never faced before.

I have a website made with Wordpress. In this site I want to include Google Analytics, so I added the following snippet into my `<head>`. (With the proper UA, of course)

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

Now, when the page loads, the following cookies are set automatically: `_ga`, `_gat_gtag_UA_XXXXXXXXX_X` and `_gid`

Now, I need to show the users an option to either accept or refuse cookies when visiting my site. For that I choose [Cookiebot](https://smarttourismcapital.eu/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=cookiebot&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550), to see this dialog.

[image]

But when the site opens, before the user had any chance to click either button, the cookies are already set.

Why is this? Am I misunderstanding anything about how cookies/GDPR work?

Comment: Do you mean the dialog disappears before you get a chance to click a button? And are you sure you placed the cookie script as the very first script in head-tag?

Comment: I am not placing any cookie script. It is all a Wordpress Plugin

Comment: Oh no! Wait! That was it! I moved the GA snippet right before `</body>` and now it works! Ok, that makes sense...